# Set notations? set B has all elements of set A except element j

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How can I write the following sentence in proper mathematical notation? I have 2 sets: $A$ and $B$, and I want to say that $B$ has all elements of $A$ except for one or more specific elements.

$B$ is a subset of $A$, but I want to identify for what elements.
e.g. $A = \{id, name, tag\}$, $B$ has everything except $id$?

Thank you

Comment: $B=A\setminus\{id\}$?

Comment: See, [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) `\setminus`. It would be $B=A\setminus\{\operatorname{id}\}$

Comment: Thank you both, very helpful.